# Issue with streaming input data with curl into a Unix pipe

Tags: bash, stream, pipe, jq, oh-my-zsh

I am having problems streaming data into a unix pipe.

Here is my command:

```
curl http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps |  jq  '.event.event_name'
```

Here is the error I get:

```
zsh: command not found:  jq
```

Can someone please help?

**edit**: jq is installed properly as shown by:

```
  ~ which jq
/usr/local/bin/jq
```

Comment: You need to install `jq`. It's an external program, not part of the shell itself. If it's installed somewhere on your system, make sure it's in a directory listed in the `PATH` during the specific command that fails.

Comment: If you want to provide evidence contrary to the obvious interpretation of the error, add to your question the output of `echo "$PATH"` **run immediately before the command that fails, by the same shell instance**. That said, if the failing script is started by `cron`, be sure you're testing the PATH in the same cron-invoked script; if it's started by Jenkins or another service, likewise.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks. I have edited my post.

Comment: `jq` is definitely installed on my machine. The issue might be due to the fact that my data is being streamed and therefore the input to the pipe changes. But I am not positive this is the problem...

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is not in every service's `PATH`. Once again, if you want to rule out the obvious, make sure it's not in yours *for the specific context in which the error is observed*.

Comment: ...there are some other possible interpretations -- for instance, there's a suspicious extra space in your error message, so you could have a non-breaking space rather than a usual ASCII space in your script, which is thus treated as part of the command name rather than syntax -- but we're getting into fairly unusual situations there.

Comment: (BTW, one way to rule out some of those other interpretations is to run `set -x` to enable trace-level logging).

Comment: I can confirm that `/usr/local/bin` is listed in `echo "$PATH"`

Comment: Thank you; that helps. Could you also add the `set -x` logs from your failing command? (`zsh -x script` will start the script with xtrace logging already enabled).

Comment: I have retyped the command and I don't get the error any more!

Comment: Great! I'll revise the duplicate list to point to another command-not-found instance caused by a non-breaking space, vs one caused by the program not being installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Charles Duffy!